# Como criar um banco no SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssms

Instalei o SQL Server, e vem o Magnament Studio, como faço para criar meu banco?
Já tentei indo por lá, e mandei autenticar pelo Windows mas dá erro.

Como crio meu banco?

Comment: Primeiro você precisa conseguir autenticar, senão fica difícil... Se não funciona autenticando pelo Windows é porque você não instalou com essa opção habilitada. Você tem a senha do usuário `sa`?

Comment: qual a senha do usuario sa? qual o login e senha??

Comment: Você deve ter criado essa senha na instalação, só você sabe. Se tiver essa informação, logue como usuário `sa` e autenticação do SQL (não do Windows)

Comment: mas nao esta autenticando nada, se eu nao coloquei na instalação, como fica?

Comment: Cara, se nada adianta, por que não reinstala o SQL? Presta atenção no instalador, uma das etapas são as opções de autenticação.

Comment: E se não souber o que fazer durante a instalação, talvez possa ser respondido aqui.

Comment: Tente dar uma olhada neste link, ele possui um tutorial de instalação, que você pode seguir: http://www.profissionaisti.com.br/2013/09/tutorial-instalacao-do-microsoft-sql-server-2012/

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda:
http://sqlserverzest.com/2013/08/20/sql-server-why-is-the-sa-login-account-disabled-how-to-enable-sa-login-account/

Comment: e este link também lhe pode ser util: http://www.lansweeper.com/kb/23/SQLserver-enable-mixed-authentication.html

Comment: massa vou olhar....

Comment: vou reinstalar aqui...

Comment: como mover a conversa pra um BP?

Comment: continuo sem entrar, ja reinstalei e nada de ver opção de usuario sa, e continua sem funcionar autenticação no windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tem segredo para se conectar, vejamos os simples passos:

1 - Na opção nome do servidor coloca-se o nome do seu pc local, ex Nome-Pc/usuario

2 - Marca windows authentication e vai conectar.

Não tem erro.

Comment: Consegui, o problema era que em nome do servidor eu tava colocando apenas o nome, e não dessa forma que voce mostrou, vlw

Comment: @WarLock que bom que conseguiu resolver. Isto já estava escrito na minha reposta: **`NomeDoServidor`**, acho que você não prestou atenção nisto.

Answer (score 3):

O usuário deve ser válido ou no SQL Server ou mesmo no Windows se estiver usando autenticação delegada para a o sistema operacional.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("data source=NomeDoServidor; uid=usuario; pwd=senha;")) {
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
    connection.Open();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "create database NomeDoBancoDeDados;";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "use NomeDoBancoDeDados; create table tabela (ID int, campo1 varchar(20));";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/CreateDatabase.cs).

Claro que a criação da tabelas é um exemplo, ela não é necessária.

Alternativa para a *string* de conexão: `"Server=localhost; Integrated security=SSPI; database=master"`

Claro que dá para sofisticar mas isto deve funcionar se não tiver problemas de instalação e configuração no SQL Server. Se tiver, precisa rever esta parte. Leia a documentação antes de instalar. Entenda as implicações de cada escolha.

Mais recentemente pode fazer:

```
using var connection = new SqlConnection("data source=NomeDoServidor; uid=usuario; pwd=senha;"));
using var cmd = new SqlCommand());
connection.Open();
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText = "create database NomeDoBancoDeDados;";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandText = "use NomeDoBancoDeDados; create table tabela (ID int, campo1 varchar(20));";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: o problema é esse, não esta autenticando nada. como crio um login?

Comment: Mas a pergunta é como criar. É desta forma. Você colocou a *tag* C#, coloquei como criar em C#. Se o problema é outro, a pergunta deveria ter refletido isto. Quando você tem dúvida sobre autenticação, se não é programação, você tem que deixar isto claro. Aí até não ser se a pergunta seria *on-topic*. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy

Comment: continuo sem conseguir entrar no banco, ja teinstalei, ja tentei com usuario sa, e com autenticação no windows

Comment: É muito difícil sem ver cada passo feito. Não será fácil você conseguir ajuda pela internet. É o tipo de erro que não podemos ver porque acontece.

Comment: ate hoje nunca consegui, acessar o sql server nessa maquina, sempre da o mesmo erro: 
 Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server.

Comment: ja baixei o 2012 enterprise, marquei la na instalação autenticação por windows, e nada ate agora.